# How can a stream of data from JPA be streamed with micronaut?

Tags: rest, java-stream, reactive-programming, rx-java2, micronaut

I am currently starting to work with micronaut and kotlin. I have JPA query that results in about 1 million results.
These results i want to stream from this one micronaut service to another.

My query returns a `allQuery.resultStream` of the type `java.util.stream`.

Controller of sending service:

```
@Get("/test{value1,value2,value3}")
fun getTestObjects(
    value1: String,
    value2: String,
    value3: String
): Stream<TestObject> {
    val entries = testRepository.findAllWhere(value1, value2, value3)

    return entries
}
```

Client of receiving service:

```
@Get("/data/test{value1,value2,value3}")
override fun getTestObjects(alue1: String,
    value2: String,
    value3: String) : Stream<TestObject>
```

And JPA query looks like:

```
    val cb = entityManager.criteriaBuilder
    val cq = cb.createQuery(TestObject::class.java)

    val rootEntry = cq.from(TestObject::class.java)

    val predicates = mutableListOf<Predicate>()

    predicates.add(cb.like(rootEntry.get<String>("value1"), value1))
    predicates.add(cb.equal(rootEntry.get<String>("value2"), value2))
    predicates.add(cb.equal(rootEntry.get<Int>("value3"), value3))

    val cqAllWhere = cq.select(rootEntry)
        .where(cb.or(*predicates.toTypedArray()))

    val allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cqAllWhere)
    val entries = allQuery.resultStream

    return entries
```

My expected output would be a kind of Flowable with pushback regulation and without the sending service to first get all objects into memory because that much memory will not be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you just need to create a `Flowable` and emit the items as they become available.

```
return Flowable.create(emitter -> {

  //loop through result set
  //for each item
  emitter.onNext(item);

  //If you encounter an error
  emitter.onError(...);

  //When you're done
  emitter.onComplete();

})
```